# TypeError at / Accept() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I want to take data from user and save it to the database by using Django. Have tried to solve it. But I am not able to solve this problem and didn't find any working solution on the internet.

I'm getting this error[image]

My views.py file

```
def Accept(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get("name","")
        phone = request.POST.get("phone","")
        email = request.POST.get("email","")
        school = request.POST.get("school","")
        degree = request.POST.get("degree","")
        university = request.POST.get("university","")
        skill = request.POST.get("skill","")
        about_you = request.POST.get("about_you","")
        previous_work = request.POST.get("previous_work","")

        accept = Accept(name=name,phone=phone,email=email,school=school,degree=degree,university=university,skill=skill,about_you=about_you,previous_work=previous_work)
        accept.save()
    return render(request,"accept.html")
```

models.py

```
class profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    skill = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    about_you = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    previous_work = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
```

accept.html

{% csrf_token %}
        
        
          Name
          
        
        
            Phone
            
        
        
            Email
            
        
        
            School
            
        
        
            Degree
            
        
        
            University
            
        
        
            Skills
            
        
        
            About You
            
        
        
            Previous Work
            
        
        Submit
    
    
    enter code here

Here is the full traceback error
[image]

Comment: Your view is calling itself (recursive), and it just get one argument(request). so change your view name to another like accept_view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what might be the issue is that you are calling Accept to register a profile inside the Accept function, so basically you are calling the function and not the object profile

Suggested changes:

```
def Accept(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get("name","")
        phone = request.POST.get("phone","")
        email = request.POST.get("email","")
        school = request.POST.get("school","")
        degree = request.POST.get("degree","")
        university = request.POST.get("university","")
        skill = request.POST.get("skill","")
        about_you = request.POST.get("about_you","")
        previous_work = request.POST.get("previous_work","")

        # dont call the function but the object profile
        accept = profile(name=name,phone=phone,email=email,school=school,degree=degree,university=university,skill=skill,about_you=about_you,previous_work=previous_work)
        accept.save()
    return render(request,"accept.html")
```

Also in python, there is some naming convention:
Function name should be in lowercase while class usually use CapsWord convention : https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions

Answer (score 0):

The `Accept` you're creating here refers to your view name, so you're trying to create a view with all these kwargs, which obviously won't work.

I think you wanted to create a `profile` instance and wrote `Accept(..)` instead of `profile(..)`.